# Extrude curve with height proportional to position on path

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: blender-geonodes-setup]

I use this geonode setup to thicken and extrude a Curve/curves. Now I'm exploring if it's possible to alter the height of extrusion along the curve. (e.g. the position **on** the curve should alter the height).

I tried working **with Curve to Points** and use information from there but with no luck.

I searched this forum but could not find any information if that's possible at all?

Maybe one of you can point me in the right direction, Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to capture the curve points position and use the value to offset the points on the Z axis. I used a sine math node to make a wave effect but you don't need it. Change it to absolute to prevent the height to be negative

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That can be something like this, using random value, as we don't know how you want height to vary.

[image]

As curve profile itself cannot be changed along curve, except using radius, use a flat line as profile, then extrude using the captured value.